# Trigger action when variable value changes (Run Continuously)

Tags: python-3.x

*I have some code that queries meta-data from a radio stream. It put's the currently playing song (Artist - Title) into a variable which works fine. I would like to make this script execute continuously but only do something when the song changes. For example, script runs... Song currently playing is "Artist 1 - Title 1" and is stored into now_playing, as the script runs, I want it to detect when now_playing is actually something different than what it was previously and do an event.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import struct
import sys
try:
    import urllib2
except ImportError:  # Python 3
    import urllib.request as urllib2

url = 'http://soundcheck.xyz:8000'  # radio stream
encoding = 'latin1' # default: iso-8859-1 for mp3 and utf-8 for ogg streams
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'Icy-MetaData': 1})  # request metadata
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
metaint = int(response.headers['icy-metaint'])
for _ in range(10): # # title may be empty initially, try several times
    response.read(metaint)  # skip to metadata
    metadata_length = struct.unpack('B', response.read(1))[0] * 16  # length byte
    metadata = response.read(metadata_length).rstrip(b'\0')
    # extract title from the metadata
    m = re.search(br"StreamTitle='([^']*)';", metadata)
    if m:
        title = m.group(1)

        if title:

                break
else:
    sys.exit('no title found')

print("Now Playing:" + title.decode(encoding, errors='replace'))
print("Previous Song:" + last_song)
```

Comment: I have tried surrounding this code within a while loop with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop that runs forever:

```
prev_song = ""
while True:
    # Your code to download song goes here.......

    # Only print the result if changed
    if title != prev_song:
        prev_song = title
        print("Now Playing:" + title.decode(encoding, errors='replace'))

    # Sleep for a little bit before checking again
    time.sleep(5)
```